# react native & firestore - return vs console.log

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I run into a little problem regarding firebase and probably something regarding async functions, Im still new to react-native and js, so I fail to resolve this error on my own.

I have following code snipped:

```
lastmessage = await firebase.firestore().collection("chatrooms").doc(`${chatkeys[i]}`).collection(`${chatkeys[i]}`).orderBy("counter").limit(1).get().then(
    querySnapshot => {
        return querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
            doc.data().value;
            console.log("console log inside foreach: ", doc.data().value)
        })
    }
)
console.log(lastmessage);
```

The firestore call and my database is alright, but the problem is within return and console.log() itself. The console.log() inside my function works perfectly and logs the wanted value inside my console - on the other side, the console.log() outside my function, right below, is not working. It just returns me "undefinded" no matter what I do. This is a big problem because Im unable to reuse this retrieved data in the next part of my code.

Can somebody maybe tell me how I could fix this? [I tried already this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/fkcs70/docdata_from_firebase_returns_undefined_but/) but it did nothing to my code, still I got undefined back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array.forEach` method doesn't expect a return value from the closure.

You're probably looking for `Array.map`:

```
return querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => {
  ...
```

Next up, if you put curly braces around the close you pass into `map` (or `forEach`), you need to include a `return` statement in there too. So:

```
return querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
    return doc.data().value;
})
```

Or shorter:

```
return querySnapshot.docs.forEach(doc => doc.data().value);
```

Comment: Still not better. My result is not undefined anymore, but now it became: 
Array [undefined,]
So basicly my "undefined" result got stuffed into an Array.

Comment: I updated my answer top show the second mistake in your code that caused that problem.

Comment: Both statements in combination were the solution to my problem, everything works now. Thank you very much and greetings from germany!